# Hyper-V snapshots exist after Shut Down

Tags: hyper-v, snapshot

I'm running a virtual machine (hyper-v) on an Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit machine.

I want to increase the hard drive size but the edit button is not enabled. The notice says "...snapshots exists for this virtual machine." I already shut the machine down (I logged in and clicked "shut down"), but it still gives me the same message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. Delete the snapshot. Just shutting a VM down will not magically make it forget the snapshots which were taken previously.

So, delete the snapshot tree. This will require the virtual machine to be off unless you are running Hyper-V on Server 2012. Then, once this is done, you can expand it.

Comment: Just as additional note: the reason snapshots are not automatically merged is that they are an administrative fast backup. Snapshot, install software - problems, roll back. Would be against their use to roll back or merge automatically.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed on Hyper-V in Windows 8.1 that Hyper-V Manager had to be restarted after deleting the checkpoints for edit vhd to be enabled.

Comment: No, it needed to merge the VHD, restarting just allowed it time to do that.